# BeautifulSoup responses with error

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to get my feet wet with BS.
I tried to work my way through the documentation butat the very first step I encountered already a problem.

This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=5....1b&per_page=250&accuracy=1&has_geo=1&extras=geo,tags,views,description')

print(soup.prettify())
```

This is the response I get:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 189
'"%s" looks like a URL. Beautiful Soup is not an HTTP client. You should probably use an     
HTTP client to get the document behind the URL, and feed that document to Beautiful Soup.' % markup)
UserWarning: "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=5...b&per_page=250&accuracy=1&has_geo=1&extras=geo,tags,views,description" 
looks like a URL. Beautiful Soup is not an HTTP client. You should 
probably use an HTTP client to get the document behind the URL, and feed that document    
to Beautiful Soup.
https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&amp;api;_key=5...b&amp;per;_page=250&amp;accuracy;=1&amp;has;_geo=1&amp;extras;=geo,tags,views,description
```

Is it because I try to call http**s** or is it another problem?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Save the web page locally then use soup on that file.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are passing URL as a string. Instead you need to get the page source via [`urllib2`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) or [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/):

```
from urllib2 import urlopen  # for Python 3: from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=5....1b&per_page=250&accuracy=1&has_geo=1&extras=geo,tags,views,description'
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(URL))
```

Note that you don't need to call `read()` on the result of [`urlopen()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen), `BeautifulSoup` allows the first argument to be a file-like object, `urlopen()` returns a file-like object.

Answer (score 3):

The error says everything, you are passing a URL to Beautiful Soup. You need to first get the website content, and only then pass the content to BS.

To download content you can use urlib2

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.example.com/')
html = response.read()
```

and later

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

Comment: Hey, I tried to figure out which answer was posted first and it said both "answered 29 mins ago". So I thought I upvote one and accept the other. I was not sure how to this correctly. I wanted to accept the answer that came first.