# InsecureRequestWarning + MarkupResemblesLocatorWarning:

Tags: python

I'd like to scrape a site for my office work. I am learning each day. I need your support guys.

Here is the Code:

```
url = https://www.eprocure.gov.bd/partner/ViewTenderPaymentDetails.jsp?payId=33767442&uId=12381&tenderId=860992&lotId=1332668&payTyp=ps)
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0","Accept-Encoding": "\*","Connection": "keep-alive"}
requests.get(url, verify=False, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(url,'html.parser').textprint(soup)
```

Result:

```
InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'www.eprocure.gov.bd'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#tls-warnings
warnings.warn(
1099: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'www.eprocure.gov.bd'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#tls-warnings
warnings.warn(
57: MarkupResemblesLocatorWarning: The input looks more like a URL than markup. You may want to use an HTTP client like requests to get the document behind the URL, and feed that document to Beautiful Soup.
soup = BeautifulSoup(url,'html.parser').text
```

Please help me with scraping the site. I've just started coding.

Answer (score 0):

InsecureRequestWarning is actually described in the warning you see in the output.

You have disabled the certificate verification (verify=False), hence made your request insecure.

You should be careful with such requests. If you want to disable this warning, see [this article](https://codeigo.com/python/disable-insecurerequestwarning/). Otherwise, follow the link from the warning message and read more details about the [SSL verification](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/user-guide.html#ssl).

Regarding BS part, you are passing the URL as a string to the constructor, instead, you should pass the [content of the response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24768904/23182657).

The following code works for me (with InsecureRequestWarning):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.eprocure.gov.bd/partner/ViewTenderPaymentDetails.jsp?payId=33767442&uId=12381&tenderId=860992&lotId=1332668&payTyp=ps"
headers = {
   "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0",
   "Accept-Encoding": "*",
   "Connection": "keep-alive",
}

response = requests.get(url, verify=False, headers=headers)
if response.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    # Continue with your parsing here
    # Continue with your parsing here
    # Continue with your parsing here

    print(soup.prettify())
else:
    print(f"Failed to retrieve the webpage. Status code: {response.status_code}")
```

Comment: Thanks bro. Is there any way that I contact you directly??

Comment: @SubrotoPaul, SO is not a social network :) Hence there is no DM.
In case you have some issues, you can do research, and if no answer is found, you can raise a question. If the question is clear, then someone definitely will help you with the answer.


A side note: if the answer helps you, tick it as the one that helped you (green tick near the answer). This will remove the question from the list of unanswered questions, so the users won't be distracted by already resolved issues.

Comment: Bro Please help me.
I nned to do set a loop. /tr[1~10] and get back to dashboard. How can I  do so.
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div/div[3]/table1/tbody/tr[1]/td[8]/a/img')).click();

Comment: @SubrotoPaul, how does this question belong to the question in the original post? StackOverflow doesn't work like this. See my comment above.And also please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Anyway, in a nutshell, if you need to loop over the rows over your table you need to find the table element, then find all the rows of the table by using driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,''//table//tr). This will give you a list of rows that you can you in the loop (for el in elements)